# Integrating WebRTC with XMPP server

Tags: java, javascript, xmpp, webrtc

I am developing a web application for video conference using XMPP and WebRTC. How to integrate WebRTC with a local XMPP server as a signaling server?

Comment: What solution did you keep ? Thx :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several projects you should be looking at:

Higher level:

- [goWebRTC.me](https://gowebrtc.me/)

Lower level:

- [strophe.jingle](https://github.com/ESTOS/strophe.jingle) (use with [Strophe.JS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/))
- [jsjac-jingle](https://github.com/valeriansaliou/jsjac-jingle) (use with [JSJaC](https://github.com/sstrigler/JSJaC))

All should work with any XMPP server, all you need is a [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/bosh/) HTTP endpoint for them to connect to, which may be provided by your XMPP server or a separate BOSH connection manager.

Comment: Hey i am also developing a android application  for video conference using XMPP and WebRTC ...can you please tell me the way to use goWebRTC in my code ...thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Otalk](http://otalk.org/) as bulk of tools for making web-baset IM applications.

Their Github profile: https://github.com/otalk